# Mac OSX Lion and libiconv

Tags: osx-lion, libiconv

I am running FreeSWITCH on Mac OSX Lion, after great pains getting it to compile. When I run the app I get this error:

```
Reason: Incompatible library version: mod_XXX.so requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0**
```

I've googled around and this seems to be a generic problem. I went to gnu.org and downloaded the latest version of libiconv, and installed it. After that my Mac went haywire. The processor kept spinning, and when I restarted OSX wouldn't boot at all (left in the grey Apple screen spinning forever). I took it to the Apple store and they recommended an OS re-install. I did so and got back up.

Now I'm scared to re-upgrade libiconv. Can anyone suggest an OSX Lion-compatible version?

Answer (score 2):

For goodness sake, don't put it /usr/lib - put it in /usr/local/lib or /opt/lib, and put them in your LD_Library_Path.  NEVER overwrite your /usr/lib or /Library/Framework.

To fix it, boot with your recovery disk, and recover your /usr/lib from your Time Machine backup.